# How to convert DjVu to Mobi with re-flowable text?

Tags: djvu, mobi

I want to convert a DjVu Ebook to Mobi. All the options I tried to far resulted in Mobi ebooks without re-flowable text. Is there a solution to do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try [calibre - E-book management](https://calibre-ebook.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following online converter: https://djvu2mobi.djvu-pdf.com/

I think it does what you are looking for and produces reflowalbe Mobi ebooks from DjVus which also include images.